# How can we reuse already prepared UFT siebel HI(High Interactivity) automation scripts for Siebel Open UI application.?

Tags: ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft, siebel

Is there any way to reuse our UFT Siebel High Interactivity automation scripts for Siebel Open UI application. We  have worked for Siebel HI application for the last 3 release (R1,R2,R3) and automated the Siebel HI application using UFT. Now we have migrated to Siebel Open UI app. Just wanted to know can we reuse the Siebel HI scripts for Siebel open UI app for UFT automation. if yes , then what is the procedure to do that?? Please let me know if anybody knows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no upgrade path between Siebel HI (`Sieb*` objects) and Siebel Open UI (`SblOUI*` objects).

Comment: I was waiting for your reply. I have seen on some of the forum and a guy from ADP  asked me to how to re-use in one the interview. when I asked the same from him he replied  we can  re-use those however I did not get chance to ask him how can we proceed.